# CSOM The request uses too many resources error while provisioning web

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom

I am provisioning web on SharePoint online using following CSOM code(provided hosted app), but intermediately we are getting "**`The request uses too many resources`**" error.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url))
{


    WebCreationInformation webCreationInformation = new WebCreationInformation();
    webCreationInformation.Title = "Site 101";
    webCreationInformation.Description = "new site";
    webCreationInformation.Url = "Site101";
    webCreationInformation.WebTemplate = "BLANKINTERNETCONTAINER#0";
    webCreationInformation.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = ture;
    var newWeb = clientContext.Web.Webs.Add(webCreationInformation);
    clientContext.Load(newWeb);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Any idea what could be possible root cause, 
Our request doesn't have more than 2MB data, simple request to create subsite.

Comment: Are you creating site from custom site template?

Comment: There is a similar thread, without solution http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141969/csom-site-provisioning-error-the-request-uses-too-many-resources
Could you check with Fiddler, what is the ErrorMessage that the server sends in the response? Do you have the publishing feature activated on you site colletion? Do you have the same problem when creating a simple team site or if you create the Publishing site via the web UI? Could you check in the ULS log what errors got logged on the server side? You can increase the Trace level (up to VerboseEx) if you need more info in the logs.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor: BLANKINTERNETCONTAINER#0 is a Publishing Portal, see http://www.funwithsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2013-site-templates-codes-for-powershell/

Comment: ohh! I see. Have a look on my answer.

Comment: and unless if it is the root web of a site collection, you should use the CMSPUBLISHING#0 web template instead of BLANKINTERNETCONTAINER#0, as far as I see

Comment: webCreationInformation.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = ture; should be =true.  Try to wait a few seconds before doing clientContext.Load(newWeb); . Or try to do execute query before clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); before load..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `RequestTimeout` in your code.

```
clientContext.RequestTimeout = 10 * 60 * 1000;
```

## References

- [CSOM site provisioning error: The request uses too many
  resources](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3a328eae-4f93-49b8-b824-aed42594e34f/csom-site-provisioning-error-the-request-uses-too-many-resources?forum=appsforsharepoint)
- [Creating site using javascript object model error: The request uses
  too many resources](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/73984/21421)

Comment: Hi Atish,

Thanks for your response, I've tried changes you mention but still getting same error intermediately.

Comment: What happens when you create site using this template manually?

Comment: No error while creating site manually or via console app using same code